# jquerymobile web app demo not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building 1 app using phonegap; and I have a demo web to show how to use app.

In the demo web have a link to demo app for poeple want to try before download into their phone.

Everything work fine in firefox but when i run demo app in chrome and IE 9, it does not work.

I try some issus and know jquerymobile not work.

This is my web:

http://smartphone.thnt.vn/gheptranhtu.html

And this is demo app:

http://smartphone.thnt.vn/VietGames/GhepTranhTu/Web/index.html

I am dumper, plsease help me!

Thanks for reading!!!

Comment: Jquery mobile not working! if i remove it, app demo display but i dont want remove it

Comment: Can you again add jQuery Mobile to your demo? We cant solve your problem unless we can test it.

Comment: i faced the same problem.is there a any solution?